# How can I install topicmodels package in R?

Tags: r, macos, terminal

I am trying to install the package called [topicmodels](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topicmodels/) in R and I have not had success. Here's what I have tried...

Action:
Install the package using `install.packages("topicmodels")`

Result:

```
package ‘topicmodels’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘topicmodels’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)
```

So there I said okay let's install from source

Action:
`install.packages("/Users/my_name/Downloads/topicmodels_0.2-1.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")`

Result:

```
* installing *source* package ‘topicmodels’ ...
** package ‘topicmodels’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c cokus.c -o cokus.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c common.c -o common.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c ctm.c -o ctm.o
ctm.c:29:10: fatal error: 'gsl/gsl_rng.h' file not found

include gsl/gsl_rng.h

1 error generated.
make: *** [ctm.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘topicmodels’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/topicmodels’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/me/Downloads/topicmodels_0.2-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

So then I researched this gsl thing and came upon [this link](http://theoryno3.blogspot.com/2010/12/installing-topicmodels-r-package.html). And for the moment I thought all of my problems were gone and when I finally follow these directions. I get the following error (in the terminal)...

```
Warning in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) :
  using pax extended headers
ERROR: cannot extract package from ‘topicmodels.tar.gz’
```

Comment: What flavour of Linux? Did you use your OS package to install gsl-dev or gsl-devel package?

Comment: Mac OSX 10.9.3 Mavericks what do you mean by OS package?

Comment: http://www.brianomeara.info/tutorials/brownie/gsl

Comment: @user2801122 OS = Operating System. I overlooked the fact that you were on a Mac, partly because you didn't both formatting any of the content of your question.

Comment: tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'gsl-1.6.tar.gz'

Comment: That's the error I get. Still working on it

Comment: I have now install gls using sudo port install gsl in the terminal

Comment: Macports installation of external packages often cause failure. Furthermore, you have not specified which of the two Mac versions (the SnowLeopard one or the "true" Mavericks one) of R 3.1.0 that you are using. I know that SO frowns on suggestions to post on R-SIG-Mac but that _is_ where you will find the most knowledgeable people about this sort of problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all you have to install `gsl`. Once you have that installed you can try to install the R package. You can download gsl from [here](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/) (there you can pick the latest version `gsl-latest.tar.gz`).  Once it's been downloaded, install it by doing the following:

1. Decompress the downloaded file (in my case the "latest" file contained this version: `gsl-1.16`)
2. Open the "Terminal"
3. Then (using the Terminal), move inside the folder that you created on step 1. In my case I had the file on the folder called "Downloads", so I moved to the newly created folder by doing:

   ```
   cd Downloads/gsl-1.16
   ```
4. Once you are within that folder run the following commands (in order):

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
5. After doing it you won't get the previous error saying `fatal error: 'gsl/gsl_rng.h' file not found`, so you can try again the installation.
6. Now go back to your R environment (e.g., RStudio) to try again to install the package by doing:

   ```
   install.packages("PATH_TO_TOPIC_MODELS.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source").
   ```

I had the same problem, and after doing this I got the R package correctly installed, I hope it also works in your case.

Comment: Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘tm’ 0.5-10 is being loaded, but >= 0.6 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘topicmodels’

Comment: Thats what I got. I was soooo close. :( Thanks though nestoralvaro!

Comment: This worked for me, though I did also have to install some other packages that topicmodels seems to view as dependencies. Thanks!

Comment: In step 6, I am doing: install.packages("topicmodels")  . But it still gives me same error. Could u tell me what is 'PATH_TO_TOPIC_MODELS.tar.gz'?

Comment: I realise this is old but simply `sudo apt-get install gsl-bin libgsl0-dev` worked for me, for anyone who comes across this.

Comment: @AkhilNair yes that worked for me, and mucking about with ~/.R/Makevars didn't. libgs10-dev was what I was missing.

Comment: on ubuntu 18.04 `sudo apt-get install libgsl-dev`

Answer (score 6):

If you already using homebrew. It is better and faster to fix with variables than installing gsl manually from source.

1. Install gsl with homebrew `brew install gsl`
2. Edit `~/.R/Makevars` and add.

   PKG_LIBS=-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib
   CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/gsl/include
   LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/gsl/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas

Comment: If anyone is coming across this in 2019, I was able to install `topicmodels` after running step 1 and didn't need step 2. macOS Mojave version 10.14.4

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Linux based on Debian, that's my solution:

1. Using terminal run `sudo apt install gsl-bin libgsl-dbg libgsl-dev libgsl25 libgslcblas0`;
2. Then, using R console, run `install.packages("topicmodels",dependencies =T)`;

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 1):

Using Ubuntu 22.04, before I ran `sudo apt install libgsl-dev`, and then in R command prompt I ran `install.packages("topicmodels")`.