# I can't install topicmodels package on OSX in R

Tags: r, package

I am have been having alot of trouble trying to install the topicmodels package. I have tried everything. When doing the following:

```
install.packages("/path/to/the/package/topicmodels.tar.gz",type="source")
```

but end up getting the following:

```
Installing package into ‘/Users/Library/R/3.1/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
inferring 'repos = NULL' from the file name
Warning in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) :
  using pax extended headers
ERROR: cannot extract package from ‘/Users/Desktop/Rfolder/topicmodels.tar.gz’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/Desktop/Rfolder/topicmodels.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

anyone have any idea? when I try to install this package using `install.packages("topicmodels")` I get:

```
package topicmodels is available as a source package but not as a binary
Warning in install.packages :
  package topicmodels is not available (for R version 3.1.0)`
```

This is the reason I am attempting to install this package from its source. I am trying to install this on OSX mavericks. Please help!

Comment: Are you trying to install it on OS X Mavericks?

Comment: Yes, you got it right

Comment: According to this link (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topicmodels/index.html), binaries are not yet available for OS X Mavericks.

Comment: so theres absolutely no way around this?

Comment: Do a proper install of the development tools, then can compile from source. Or just use the SL version of R inside Mavericks. Then you can install from binary.

Comment: SnowLeopard version of R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me when trying to install "topicmodels" package on MacOS Mavericks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24245311/3745085